# How to filter a Kendo UI MVC grid using a clienttemplate field

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I have a kendo ui grid and a field as below:
columns.Bound(c => `c.ProjectManagerId).ClientTemplate("#:ProjectManagerName#").Title("Project Manager").Filterable(p => p.*UserAnotherFieldHere*("ProjectManagerName"));`
I am showing the projectManagerName but the field is Id. How can I sort and filter base on Name field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using client sied filtering then you can use a custom filter operator

```
dataSource.filter({
    field: "FieldName",
    operator: function(item, value){
        //implement your logic
    },
    value: 
})
```

And for sorting:

```
{ field: "id", title: "id" },
        { 
            field: "FieldName", 
            title: "FieldNameTitle",
            sortable: {
                compare: function (a, b) {
                    return implement your logic here
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm Using MVC and JSON dataBinding. Can I use anything as a setting for Request Json call?

Comment: You can use server side filtering, sorting and paging. You can use parameter map to pass grid options (filtering, sorting and paging) to server, and there you can implement your custom logic.